# How to sort mutliple columns by data in one?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-workspace

I have two columns A and B, A has checkboxes that when set to `TRUE` it fills the adjacent cell in B green and strikes the text through.  I want to create a filter that sorts columns A and B by the data in column A. so all the `TRUE`  checkboxes are at the bottom as well as the adjacent B cell.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description on your search/research efforts as is suggested in [How to Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you read [Sort & filter your data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) from the Google Sheets documentation? if Column A only contains checkboxes, then sorting Column A  by "A->Z" will put the checked boxes and the adjacent conditionally formatted boxes at the bottom of the sort range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i wen tinto the documentation and figured it out.

1. First select the column you want to sort by then the other columns
2. Data > Sort Range By `Column` A - Z